# Why console.log shows only part of the number resulting from 0.1+0.2=0.30000000000000004

Tags: javascript, binary, ieee-754

This question wasn't asked on stackoverlow yet! I'm not asking why 0.1+0.2 doesn't equal 0.3, I'm asking very different thing! Please read the question before marking it as a duplicate.

---

I've written this function that shows how JavaScript stores float numbers in 64 bits:

```
function to64bitFloat(number) {
    var f = new Float64Array(1);
    f[0] = number;
    var view = new Uint8Array(f.buffer);
    var i, result = "";
    for (i = view.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var bits = view[i].toString(2);
        if (bits.length < 8) {
            bits = new Array(8 - bits.length).fill('0').join("") + bits;
        }
        result += bits;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I want to check if the result of `0.1+0.2` is actually stored as it's shown in the console `0.30000000000000004`. So I do the following:

```
var r = 0.1+0.2;
to64bitFloat(r);
```

The resulting number is:

```
0 01111111101 0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100
```

Now, let's convert it to the binary:

Calculated exponent:

```
01111111101 = 1021
1021 - 1023 = -2
```

Get it all together,

```
1.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100 x 2 ** -2 =
0.010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100
```

Now, if we convert the resulting number into decimal using [this converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/), we get:

```
0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
```

Why doesn't console show the whole number, instead of just it's more significand digits?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, please read the question

Comment: It's probably a duplicate of something else but not the one marked earlier. PLEASE READ THE QUESTION. This question is NOT ABOUT FLOATING POINT ADDITION. It is about PRECISION.

Comment: This may be of interest though it does not exactly answer the question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: @slebetman, thanks, I'll take a look. This could give me a hint to understand the inconsistency

Comment: Relevant section in the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type

Comment: Generally when printing numbers js will convert it to string via the internal `.toString()` method but I couldn't find any documentation on the precision. Then I found `.toPrecision()`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Thanks for that. I was googling for it but couldn't find anything

Comment: There is same question asked on https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions. And they say "Numbers in JavaScript are all treated with floating point precision, and as such, may not always yield the expected results." I don't know the proper source though.

Comment: @mrkm, thanks, but the question asks very different thing)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) method is non-standard. In Firefox, you can specify the number of decimal with a [format specifier](https://github.com/DeveloperToolsWG/console-object/blob/master/api.md#format-specifiers)

```
console.log('%.60f', 0.1 + 0.2)
```

gives

```
0.300000000000000044408920985006261616945266723632812500000000
```

Which is the same number as the one given by your converter.

Note that, this doesn't work in chrome.

In conclusion:

- Javascript number are stored with the IEEE 754-2008 double-precision 64-bit binary format.
- String representation of a number is defined in the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type).
- console.log method is browser dependent and the Firefox implementation allows to specify an arbitrary number of decimal places to display numbers .

Comment: is that the maximum precision, can we get the number I ended up with using my function?

Comment: cool, thanks. Can you please summarize in your answer what the guys in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339683/why-console-log-shows-only-part-of-the-number-resulting-from-0-10-2-0-300000000#comment62196852_37339683) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339683/why-console-log-shows-only-part-of-the-number-resulting-from-0-10-2-0-300000000#comment62196830_37339683) comment said. I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't have to write such a long question. What you could do is just open console and type:

> var a = 0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125;
>
> console.log(a);

that would still give you result - 0.30000000000000004 (at least in Google chrome console).

And the reason why it is like that, is because limitations of JS, which only allow to show 16 chars of a float. You can read more in answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19613321/3014041

Comment: the answer you linked to is wrong. double precision has 52 significant digits, not 16

Comment: Please read wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format, it is 52 bit, which gives 15–17 significant decimal digits precision.

Comment: we're probably talking about different things then

Comment: I think we indeed are talking about different things. Are you saying that JavaScript can't show more that 17 digits **after** the radix point when presented in base-10 system?

Comment: @naneri doubles have 53 bits (which it says in the document you link).